# How to get an array from ASP.Net WebMethod to Ajax using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am calling an webmethod from ajax, and I want to return an array. I tried this below code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  url: "adminCopyCrystalReport.aspx/getAllDirectoryNames",
  //data: JSON.stringify({
  //    //"dirLocation": $(this).children('.pathValue').text()
  //    "dirLocation": correctPath
  //}),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    alert('Success = ' + data.d);
  },
  error: function (result) {
    alert("Error");
  }
});
```

```csharp
public static GetFolderDetails[] getAllDirectoryNames()
{
  string paths = "~CrystalReportFiles/";
  List<GetFolderDetails> details = new List<GetFolderDetails>();

  foreach (var dirr in new DirectoryInfo(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@paths)).GetDirectories())
  {
    //dir.Add(dirr.Name);
  }

  GetFolderDetails fd = new GetFolderDetails();
  fd.fullFolder = "xxx";
  fd.folderName = "ccc";
  fd.urlPath = "eee";

  return details.ToArray();
}
```

It throws a 500 Internal Server Error. If I return a string I get the output

Answer (score 0):

Try to serialize the array (using `Newtonsoft`) and use `Response.Write()`:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public void getAllDirectoryNames()
{
  string paths = "~CrystalReportFiles/";
  List<GetFolderDetails> details = new List<GetFolderDetails>();

  // Add items to details list

  // Serialize the list using Newtonsoft
  // var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details);

  // Serialize the list using System.Web.Script.Serialization
  var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(details);

  // Send the response back to ajax success callback
  Response.Write(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: what is newtonsoft?. it throws error if i add `using Newtonsoft`

Comment: it is still internal server error. and why did you remove static from the method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are mising below configration

In `Global.asax` file inside `Application_Start` method comment below line

```
//RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Make sure that you `EnablePageMethods` in your `ScriptManager`

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
```

Comment: Mostly in your master page HTML of directly in your page if you don't use the master page, And if you don't have one you need to add it.